# Display acf taxonomy attachment

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

On wordpress, using ACF I've added a taxonomy field to the attachment to all images. I now want to display the taxonomy field in the html 'id="the-taxonomy">'. My main goal is using it as an anchor. So you'd go to my website - notreallyruby.com/work/toast#the-taxonomy.

I cannot seem to display the taxonomy tag in the html.
At the moment it is just displaying the first random tag.

The html looks like this - https://paste.pics/98d4ab6b52b0951c31df62b54534b1b7 and the attachment looks like this: https://paste.pics/06d35483028b09520dc3d822d10d06e5 At the moment it says id="Apples" I want it to say "business card"

Id appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content','new_content');
function new_content($content) {

$term = get_queried_object();
$test = get_field('tag_cat_acf', get_post_thumbnail_id());

{

$content = str_replace('<img ', '<img data-attr="'.  $test->name .'" ', $content);
return $content; 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, NotReallyRuby. It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. That';s the main question for me, but also, in your code,`$test` would have to be an object with a name property. What field type are you using, and why and how are you applying it? It's also not clear why you're trying to capture a `$term` object at all, since it's not used.

Comment: @CKMacLeod hi, so using ACF I've added a taxonomy field to the attachment to all images. I now want to display the taxonomy field in the html 'id="the-taxonomy">'. My ultimate goal is using it as an anchor. So you'd go to my website - notreallyruby.com/work/toast#the-taxonomy

Comment: I'm still not getting it, and I'm frankly not sure you understand how the various functions you're using work or are supposed to work. The images are assigned taxonomy terms ( tags or categories) different from the ones that apply to to whichever post they appear in? You want the images to work as anchor links? Why a data attribute if what you're trying to change is an ID ( leaving aside issues with that for the moment)?

Comment: Yeah I'm fairly new to php so I'm sorry if I use the wrong terminology. The html looks like this - https://paste.pics/98d4ab6b52b0951c31df62b54534b1b7 and the attachment looks like this: https://paste.pics/06d35483028b09520dc3d822d10d06e5 At the moment it says id="Apples" I want it to say "business card"

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand what you want to achieve, even if I still don't understand why. It seems that what you want to do is "filter" the id attributes of specific gallery image "items" in WP Gallery Blocks. Using `the_content` filter will likely produce scattershot results if practicable at all.  You might want to withdraw this question and create a different, more focused one. However, you might want to make sure that you want to use a a WP Gallery Block for your purposes before tunneling down this particular rabbit hole.